# iOS NavigationController back icon

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to change the back button's icon from arrow to something else? (in the navigation bar)

I didn't find solution in the preferences of the storyboard

Answer (score 2):

If your deployment target is at least iOS 7 you can use `backIndicatorImage` and `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` properties.
If you want to change all navigation bars in application, I'd suggest use `appearance` method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let backIcon = UIImage(named: "customImage")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backIcon
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backIcon
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This used not to be possible (pre-iOS 7), but you could use your own custom UIBarButtonItem, and implement logic to simulate the back button.

Add this code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "customImage"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "buttonClicked:")
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

and implement the buttonClicked function:

```
func buttonClicked(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```